# Run a Windows Batch File Through Wine Using Ruby on Rails in Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, command-line, wine

I'm developing a web application using Ruby on Rails and running it on a Linux (ubuntu) server. My backend processing is based on a Windows .bat file that calls a network of other .bat files based on a list of about 5 parameters.

So basically, I'm trying to call the initial batch file with command line preferences through wine in my Rails application.

For example, this is similar to what I use to successfully run the code in the ubuntu terminal:

```
wine cmd.exe /C InitialCallFile.bat Directory/Input.xml Directory/Output.xml param1 param2
```

I tried to call it with the System and %x commands in Ruby. For example:

```
System "wine cmd.exe /C InitialCallFile.bat self.infile self.outfile self.param1 self.param2"
system wine cmd.exe InitialCallFile.bat [self.infile, self.outfile, self.param1, self.param2]
%x[wine cmd.exe /C InitialCallFile.bat self.infile self.outfile self.param1 self.param2]
```

and other similar variations

However, the program doesn't recognize cmd and comes back with the error:
undefined local variable or method `cmd'

How should I go about correctly calling an application in wine using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Calling batch files running under Wine on an Ubuntu server does not sound like a good idea. Maybe you should rewrite those batch files into shell or Ruby scripts?

Comment: I'm stuck with the Ubuntu server due to cost differences. I considered rewriting the batch files, but there are a significant amount of them and would require a non-trivial amount of work. So if there was a way to call them through Wine on Ubuntu (even if it may not be the best design), that could serve as a quick fix for now. Then I could go back and transition them over time

Comment: I would convert the bat files to sh syntax

Comment: You're gonna have a bad time... I wouldn't say its impossible but like Blender said, I would definitely recommend rewriting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) (note the lower case `s`), preferably the multi-argument form:

```
system 'wine', 'cmd.exe', '/C', 'InitialCallFile.bat', self.infile, self.outfile, self.param1, self.param2
```

Note that the constant parts are string literals whereas as the variable parts (such as `self.infile`) are method calls and so they're not quoted.

You could also use string interpolation to build the command but that's a really bad idea and I'm not going to encourage bad habits by showing you how.

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a slight modification:
`system 'wine', 'cmd.exe', '/C', @batch_file, self.infile, self.outfile, self.param1, self.param2`

The batch file actually had to be stored in a variable or it would come back with a "syntax error, unexpected tlVAR, expecting kEND"